# how to fix PDF form displaying as unfilled in preview but filled when opened

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am attempting to fill PDF forms programmatically with PDFSharp but am running into an odd problem. After filling the fields in the document replacing their default values I save and email the PDF. When I view the PDF as a preview like in Outlook, the form fields show their default values, but when I download and open the PDF the correct values are shown.

This is how i generate the PDF files. Open the template, fill the fields and then save to new location.

```
PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(_pdfPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
if (doc.AcroForm.Elements.ContainsKey("/NeedAppearances") == false)
{
   doc.AcroForm.Elements.Add("/NeedAppearances", new PdfBoolean(true));
}
else
{
   doc.AcroForm.Elements["/NeedAppearances"] = new PdfBoolean(true);
}
PdfAcroField field = doc.AcroForm.Fields[key];
field.ReadOnly = false;
field.Value = new PdfString(row[Layout[key]].ToString());
field.ReadOnly = true;
doc.Save(newFilePath);
```

Why would it display differently depending on the viewer? how can i fix this, or is there a workaround?

I appreciate any assistance.

**EDIT**
If i open the filled in PDF (in Acrobat) and close it again I'm asked to save changes even though I haven't made any, and after saving the filled form data shows in the preview.

Comment: Hi @chris j can you share the template file that you are using?

Comment: @JoeriE Its a template of a confidential letter with sensitive info on it, so id prefer not to. but if you are looking for structure etc I can give you screenshots of the structure in PdfExplorer? Sorry i realise that this makes it alot more difficult to assist.

Comment: this might not be the most optimal solution but it might work. Since it asks you to save it after opening in Acrobat you can try to do that from your code when the document is finshed. Open the file in the background with Acrobat save it and close it. then you add it to Outlook.

Comment: I had already considered that but im generating these sometimes a few hundred at a time so that will cause considerable slowness. Id really like to know why the preview generates differently. I noticed that if i draw to the pdf with DrawString() etc then it will show up in the preview. so its something to do with filling in the fields that is the issue